# Setting image width in carousel in Android Studio

Tags: android, image, width, carousel

I'd like to have a carousel of images in my app where the single image's width is the same as the screen's width. I tried a few different things, but didn't manage to do this.

The views of the carousel are:

HorizontalScroll --> LinearLayout(horizontal) --> 4*imageView

The problem is that I can't use fill parent as width because it fills the whole LinearLayout. I could probably calculate the right widths programmatically, but I was wondering is there easier way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using `GridView` with horizontal scrolling. You can achieve almost every functionality and look that you want. 
As for example you can use a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`. Than you can align your Grid in such way, that it will have only one column - thus the image will fit the screens' width, and don't forget to set `adjustViewBounds=true`